# Adding feature layer in ArcGIS

Tags: javascript, arcgis-js-api

I am trying to add client-side feature graphics to a feature layer in a map using the following code, but nothing seems to appear on the map:

```
    function CreateFeatureLayer()  {
        featureLayer=new FeatureLayer({ 
            source:[],
            objectIdField:"OBJECTID",
            geometryType:"point",
            spatialReference: { wkid: 4326 },
            fields:[ { name:"OBJECTID", type:"oid" }, { name:"name", type:"string" }, { name:"ktypemid", type:"string" }, { name:"kmid", type:"string" }],
            renderer: { type:"simple",  symbol:{ type: "web-style",  styleName: "Esri2DPointSymbolsStyle",  name: "landmark" } },
            popupTemplate: { title: "{Name}"  }
            });

        map.add(featureLayer);

        const data=[{ LATITUDE: 37.6251, LONGITUDE: -119.085, TYPE: "Title",  NAME: "Name" }];

        let graphics=[];
        let i=0,graphic;
        for (i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
            graphic=new Graphic({
                geometry: { type: "point", latitude: data[i].LATITUDE, longitude: data[i].LONGITUDE },
                attributes: data[i]
                });
            graphics.push(graphic);
            }

        app.featureLayer.applyEdits(graphics);
    }
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong, after modeling an example. I also want to be able to use my own bitmap, rather than an ESRI icon.

Comment: What basemap are you using? .. Why are you using `FeatureLayer` instead of `GraphicLayer`? .. BTW, what do you mean with "my own bitmap"?

Comment: I am using as road layer base map. The idea is to overlay a series of geo-located icons over the map, and then show information when you hover over them or click on them. I want to use a png file to show each icon.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you problem might be when calling `applyEdits`. These function takes as a parameter an object with the features and attachments to add, update or delete. So in your example it should be,

```
app.featureLayer.applyEdits({addFeatures: graphics});
```

[ArcGIS API - FeatureLayer applyEdits](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-layers-FeatureLayer.html#applyEdits)

Anyway, based on one of the examples I made this code It might guide you,

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no"
    />
    <title>FeatureLayer Points Icons - 4.15</title>
    <style>
      html,
      body,
      #viewDiv {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
      }
    </style>

    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://js.arcgis.com/4.15/esri/themes/light/main.css"
    />
    <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/4.15/"></script>

    <script>
      require([
        "esri/Map",
        "esri/views/MapView",
        "esri/layers/FeatureLayer",
        "esri/core/promiseUtils",
        "esri/Graphic",
        "esri/geometry/Point",
      ], function(
        Map,
        MapView,
        FeatureLayer,
        promiseUtils,
        Graphic,
        Point
      ) {
        function getRandomNumber(min, ref) {
          return Math.random() * ref + min;
        }

        function getGraphics() {
          const graphics = [];
          let location = null;
          // generate 6 random points features
          for (let i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
            location = new Point({
              latitude: getRandomNumber(10, 50),
              longitude: -getRandomNumber(50, 50)
            });
            graphics.push(
              new Graphic({
                geometry: location,
                attributes: {
                  OBJECTID: i,
                  name: `F${i}`
                }
              })
            );
          }
          return graphics;
        }

        const graphics = getGraphics();

        function popupTemplateContent(feature) {
          const location = feature.graphic.geometry;
          return `lat:${location.latitude.toFixed(2)} lon:${location.longitude.toFixed(2)}`;
        }

        const view = new MapView({
          map: new Map({
            basemap: "gray-vector"
          }),
          container: "viewDiv",
          zoom: 2,
          center: [-75, 35]
        });

        view
          .when()
          .then(createLayer)
          .then(addToView)
          .catch(function(e) {
            console.error("Creating FeatureLayer failed", e);
          });

        function createLayer() {
          return new FeatureLayer({
            source: graphics,
            objectIdField: "OBJECTID",
            fields: [
              {
                name: "OBJECTID",
                type: "oid"
              },
              {
                name: "name",
                type: "string"
              }
            ],
            popupTemplate: {
              title: '{name}',
              content: popupTemplateContent
            },
            renderer: {
              type: "unique-value",
              field: "OBJECTID",
              defaultSymbol: { type: "simple-fill" },
              uniqueValueInfos: [{
                value: "0",
                symbol: {
                  type: "picture-marker",
                  url: " http://static.arcgis.com/images/Symbols/Cartographic/esriCartographyMarker_98.png",
                  width: "32px",
                  height: "32px"
                }
              }, {
                value: "1",
                symbol: {
                  type: "picture-marker",
                  url: " http://static.arcgis.com/images/Symbols/Cartographic/esriCartographyMarker_98_Red.png",
                  width: "32px",
                  height: "32px"
                }
              }, {
                value: "2",
                symbol: {
                  type: "picture-marker",
                  url: " http://static.arcgis.com/images/Symbols/Cartographic/esriCartographyMarker_98_Green.png",
                  width: "32px",
                  height: "32px"
                }
              }, {
                value: "3",
                symbol: {
                  type: "picture-marker",
                  url: " http://static.arcgis.com/images/Symbols/Cartographic/esriCartographyMarker_98_Blue.png",
                  width: "32px",
                  height: "32px"
                }
              }, {
                value: "4",
                symbol: {
                  type: "picture-marker",
                  url: " http://static.arcgis.com/images/Symbols/Cartographic/esriCartographyMarker_98_White.png",
                  width: "32px",
                  height: "32px"
                }
              }, {
                value: "5",
                symbol: {
                  type: "picture-marker",
                  url: " http://static.arcgis.com/images/Symbols/Cartographic/esriCartographyMarker_98_Yellow.png",
                  width: "32px",
                  height: "32px"
                }
              }]
            }
          });
        }

        function addToView(layer) {
          view.map.add(layer);
        }
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="viewDiv"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Finally, In my comment I momentary get confuse, that's why I ask you about using `FeatureLayer` instead of `GraphicLayer`. My bad :) .. It is the recommended way with the new API.